# How to reliably determine whether Passbook is available?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, passbook, passkit

Apple provides a dedicated method in Passkit to determine whether the PassLibrary is available:

```
[PKPassLibrary isPassLibraryAvailable]
```

This works as expected on iPhone and iPad with one exception: The iPad Air 2 returns `YES` but it seems that it does not support any UI to add a pass. Invocation of

```
[[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:aValidPass]
```

returns `nil`.

Is there any option to check reliably whether PassLibrary, including UI, is available WITHOUT having a pass beforehand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [isPassLibraryAvailable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617080-ispasslibraryavailable)

> Do not use this method to determine whether the user can add passes on this device. A device may have a pass library, but still not be able to add passes. Use the PKAddPassesViewController class’s canAddPasses() method instead.

You should use `PKAddPassesViewController` for this, which returns whether the device supports adding passes.

```
[PKAddPassesViewController canAddPasses]
```

since iOS8